# How enable tree-sitter modes (*-ts-mode) that aren't built-in?

Tags: major-mode, syntax-highlighting, tree-sitter

My Emacs (29.1) comes with the some tree-sitter modes:

```
c-ts-mode
go-ts-mode
js-ts-mode
...
```

I downloaded the compiled .dll and they work out of box.

However, there are some languages that `tree-sitter` seems to support, but I don't know how to enable them in Emacs. For example, [it supports lua](https://github.com/emacs-tree-sitter/tree-sitter-langs/tree/master/repos), but there is no `lua-ts-mode` in my Emacs, and not `list-package` doesn't show it either. So where could I get `lua-ts-mode`? Or the major modes of some languge simply don't exist even `tree-sitter` already support them?

Comment: `emacs-tree-sitter` is *not* the tree-sitter support that is build into Emacs 29.  That github repository is an earlier approach to integrating the two things.  They are quite different, and so I don't know whether that `tree-sitter-langs` section has any relevance.

Comment: @phils an early approach that supports more languages... the ecosystem is a bit weird. But thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has to write one.

“[language specific tree-sitter major mode wont show up](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78605/)” is a similar question, with an answer that goes into more detail about what needs to be written.

Comment: Thank you. I made the same (wrong) assumption that tree-sitter is a simple protocol that once you have the compiled library your edit can pick it up and work perfectly.

Comment: You’re welcome. Its an easy assumption to make, apparently.

Comment: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/lets-write-a-treesitter-major-mode just crossed my desk; you may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A package `lua-ts-mode` [was submitted](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2023-07/msg00796.html) for inclusion to *ELPA* in July 2023 and then [added upstream](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=b6659e98a4fcaa44477b64d7782243feca020418), to Emacs 30 (currently under development).

I'm also linking [the initial source](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ejohnmuhl/lua-ts-mode/log).

See also [How to Get Started with Tree-Sitter](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/how-to-get-started-tree-sitter). It covers foundational points, so may provide a couple of conceptual insights.

Comment: Sorry for this super noob question, but how could I get it from ELPA (besides downloading the source file directly)? Even after `package-refresh-content` it still doesn't show up. Edit: Ah the README has installation instructions. But I'm still a bit confused why `package-refresh-content` doesn't work if it's already on ELPA.

Comment: The package was added upstream. I've updated the answer to reflect this.